# How to parse data inside a javascript box on a website?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver

I don't know if I am using selenium wrong, but I am trying to get data from a website that has a browser game. I can see the data I am trying to capture in inspect element, but if I copy to xpath it will not recognize the xpath. https://www.mathplayground.com/ASB_TugTeamMultiplication.html

site link, so the game is in javascript. is there a way to. If you click play game, you can see players looking for match. I want to track how many people play the game and current times. The only issue I have is selenium will not see the data. I can see the data I need in inspect element. I can parse the entire page with selenium, but it will skip the javascript window. Any ideas? I am doing this in python

[image]

[image: Second picture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the node you want to scrape is contained in a `iframe` element, which is itself contained in another `iframe` as you can see from the image below.

[image]

To access elements inside a `iframe` you have to switch to it with

```
driver.switch_to.frame('game') # switch to the iframe with `id="game"`
second_iframe = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'iframe')
driver.switch_to.frame(second_iframe)
```

Then if you run `driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'text[dy]')` you will finally get your elements.

## Update

Consider this case

[image]

You can scrape the question and the answers in the following way

```
question = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[name()="text"][text()="QUESTION"]/following-sibling::*')

answers = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[name()="text"][text()="QUESTION"]/parent::*/following-sibling::*')
answers = [a.text.split('\n')[1] for a in answers]

print(f'question number {question[0].text}: {question[1].text}\nanswers: {" ".join(answers)}')
```

output

```
question number 5: 7 × 3
answers: 12 32 24 21
```

Comment: This works! Thank you. One issue I had is when I try to data by XPATH it prints []. But I will just use arrays to get to the right data

Comment: @twitterL9 Which xpath are you using that prints `[]`?

Comment: I added a picture to the post, I am trying to get the xpath of the question and answers inside the game. //*[@id="main"]/g/g/g[9]/g[1]/g[1]/text[3] is one of the xpaths I need. Though I really appreciate the iframe help I had no idea that is what was causing me to be unable to access data.

Comment: @twitterL9 I updated the answer with the code to get question and answers inside the game. If the problem is solved you may consider marking the answer as accepted by clicking ✔ on the left.

Comment: Thank you this is perfect! Can I ask how did you find the xpath? Is it something different because of the iframes?

Comment: @twitterL9 No the xpaths are not different because of the iframes. The thing is, when the nodes you want to scrape don't have a unique class or other unique attribute, then it is useful to use one particular node as starting point to select the ones of interest. In this case the node used as starting point is `*[name()="text"][text()="QUESTION"]` and is unique because no other text nodes have "QUESTION" as text